# Программа не выводит значение(Проблема с выводом TextView)

Tags: java, android

```
public void foodbuttonclick(View view){
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
    LayoutInflater inflater = MainActivity.this.getLayoutInflater();
    View mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_view, null);
    final EditText etenter = (EditText)mView.findViewById(R.id.dialogview);
    View nView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.weekandmonth, null);
    final TextView tvoutput = (TextView)nView.findViewById(R.id.textViewfood);
    builder.setTitle("Питание")
            .setMessage("Введите сумму:").setView(mView)
            .setCancelable(true)
            .setPositiveButton("Подтвердить",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                            String foodstr;
                            String foodtotalstr;
                            int foodint;
                            int foodtotal;

                            foodstr = etenter.getText().toString();
                            if (foodstr == "") {
                            foodint = Integer.valueOf(foodstr);
                            foodtotal =+ foodint;
                            foodtotalstr = String.valueOf(foodtotal);
                            tvoutput.setText(foodtotalstr);
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                            else dialog.cancel();


                        }
                    });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
}
```

dialog_view - xml файл, в котором находится EditText
dialogview - id этого edittext
weekandmonth - xml файл, в котором находится TextView
textViewfood - id этого textview

Мне необходимо, чтобы программа считала из edittext(который должен быть в alertdialog) число(строковая foodstr, которую конвертирую в переменную foodint), прибавила его к предыдущему результату(переменная foodtotal) и вывела эту сумму(новая foodtotal) в TextView
Сейчас приложение не крашит, но и не работает так, как должно(Сейчас не знаю, на каком этапе конкретно, но просто в нужной textView не появляется число).
Прошу помочь найти ошибку в коде или указать на лучший способ сделать все нужные мне операции лучшим путём.

Сам являюсь новичком-дурачком, поэтому мог совершить много ошибок.
Заранее благодарю за помощь.

Comment: прибавила, вывела - Сам!

Comment: Простите, не понял вас. Имеете ввиду, что код должен работать?